Inequality for three variables quadratic function
Let $a,b,c,d\geq 0$ and $\alpha>0$ be such that
(1) $b\leq \alpha c$
(2) $c\leq a+\alpha d$
Find the supremum  for  $\alpha $ such that there exist $A,B,C,D>0$ (dependent on $\alpha$) satisfying
$$
-a^2-b^2+2\alpha bc\leq -Aa^2-Bb^2-Cc^2+Dd^2 \quad \text{and}\quad C\geq D. 
$$
Calculate $A,B,C,D>0$ in terms of $\alpha$.
My attempt. I guess that the supremum  for $\alpha$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.
Thank you for all comments and guidance.

You are not new user, show your attempts please.

Thanks for your comment. I  have  tried  but  the  problem  is  not  easy  to solve.

I know, but maybe include some attempts, I afraid the closure of this question.

For your guess of $ \alpha$, what is the corresponding $A, B, C, D$?

is $d$ a positive number?

Yes. $d\geq 0$.

@Blind If $b = c = 0$, then for all $\alpha>0$, there exist $A, B, C, D$?

Thanks for your comment. Here, we can not choose specified numbers for $b,c$ since $a,b,c,d$ were given.

@Blind You should use @, otherwise I do not receive the notification. So, do you mean: Let $a, b, c, d\ge 0$ be given. Let $\alpha > 0$ such that $b\le \alpha c$ and $c \le a + \alpha d$. If there exist $A, B, C, D > 0$ such that $-a^2-b^2+2\alpha bc\leq -Aa^2-Bb^2-Cc^2+Dd^2$ and $C\geq D$, what is the supremum of $\alpha$?

@RiverLi. Thank you for your construction. Your statement is indeed is my question.

@Blind Do you know the source of the problem? I am afraid the original meaning is not what I mean.
